# Django - Name Error when views call model's object

Tags: python, django

I'm making a simple python3 django server for a mobile application.
But in views.py, I got errors while testing.

This is one of functions.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from bns_info.models import Character, Dungeon, Tactics, Team
import json
import hashlib
import time

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.body.decode("utf-8")
        receivedData = json.loads(data)

        receivedName = receivedData['characterName']
        character = Character.objects.get(name=receivedName)
        team = Team.objects.filter(teamNum=character['teamNum'])
        teamDungeonType = Dungeon.objects.filter(dType=team['dType'])

        retValue = {character['teamNum']:teamDungeonType['dType']}
        return JsonResponse(retValue, safe=False)

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Request is not POST method.')
```

and  this is my model design.

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    teamNum = models.IntegerField(db_column='teamNum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Character'
```

And I got few errors, this is the message.

`Internal Server Error: /login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Dalek_Sec/BnS_Info/Server/appServer/bns_info/views.py", line 18, in login
    character = Character.objects.filter(name=receivedName)
NameError: name 'Character' is not defined
[04/Jun/2017 21:11:54] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 60733`

I thought It's enough that I defined 'Character' in models but django says Character is not defined. What's the problem???

Comment: Next time please don't post errors as images. WHat has happened here is that oyu have forgotten to import the Character model

Comment: I wrote "from (appname).models import *" but It still says same error

Comment: Well if that's your import statement I am not surprised. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried `from .models import Character`??

Comment: Oh, I worked with copy file and didn't paste to original directory lol.. form ~.models. import char is working and I met another error: Character object is not subscriptable, haha. thank you for advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your view like this,

```
def login(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        data = request.body.decode("utf-8")
        receivedData = json.loads(data)
        receivedName = receivedData['characterName'] 
        character = Character.objects.get(name=receivedName) 
        team = Team.objects.get(teamNum=character.teamNum) 
        teamDungeonType = Dungeon.objects.get(dType=team.dType) 
        retValue = {character.teamNum : teamDungeonType.dType} 
        return JsonResponse(retValue, safe=False) 
    else: 
        return HttpResponse('Request is not POST method.')
```

Comment: Thank you. I totally thought wrong. I had to use '.' to call object's property but I used ['~'] ..!! It works well and thank you all :)